# remove xml tags with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, python-2.6

I want to remove the xml tags from the file "new.xml" and put the data according to the print statement.

I have tried with:

```
    from lxml import etree

    tree = etree.parse("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\new.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()      
    for text in root.iter():
      print text.text
```

XML code is:

```
<connection>
<rhel>

<runscript>y</runscript>
<username>useranme</username>
<password>passw</password>
<store>None</store>
<port>2</port>
<host>192.168.73.56</host>
<logdirectory>logs</logdirectory>
</rhel>

</connection>
```

I got the following output as:

```
yes
username
passw
None
2
192.168.73.56
logs
```

But I want to print it as:

```
is it a new connection: yes
username: username
password: passw
value: none
connections: 2
host: 192.168.73.56
log dir : logs
```

Comment: What does the XML file look like?

Comment: with the output we can not take the line by line value?

Comment: I don't think it's a good thing to rely on *that* output. It is only the `repr`esentation of the root, and not the recommended way of accessing XML files. Also, to make people help you better, give them something to test your code on.

Comment: Please find the xml file and xml parse code above in the mentioned question

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse according to the structure of the XML file. For this you can make a loop through the children, and see the tag name and text of each.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

connections = []
for node in root.findall('rhel'): # for all the 'rhel' nodes, children of the root 'connections' node
    connections.append({info.tag: info.text for info in node}) # Construct a dictionary with the (tag, text) as (key, value) pair.

print connections

for conn in connections:
    print '='*20
    print """is it a new connection: {runscript}
username: {username}
password: {password}
value: {store}
connections: {port}
host: {host}
log dir : {logdirectory}""".format(**conn)
```

The way you were doing it, you could try: `repr(root)`. You'll get what is being printed. But it is not recommended, for many reasons:

1. The output is not guaranteed to be in the order you have it now.
2. This is not the structure of the XML file.
3. There are lots of blank lines, and it is expected to be like that.
4. That's just not how you parse XML :)

Hope it helps.

**Update**:

You can use `connections.append(dict((info.tag, info.text) for info in node))` instead of the other line for Python<2.7 . This notation was not supported before that I guess.

Or, ultimately, you can do it as such:

```
c = {}
for info in node:
    c[info.tag] = info.text
connections.append(c)
```

Also if on Python 2.6, I guess the format might not work too. Replace it with this, the old string formatting:

```
    print """is it a new connection: %(runscript)s
username: %(username)s
password: %(password)s
value: %(store)s
connections: %(port)s
host: %(host)s
log dir : %(logdirectory)s""" % conn
```

Comment: i am getting this error:     connections.append({info.tag: info.text for info in node}) # Construct a dic
tionary with the (tag, text) as (key, value) pair.
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It must have something to do with the version you are using. I'll update my answer

Comment: @SuryaGupta Then either of the 2 other methods should work for you :)